# How to get the size of a string?

Tags: python

I have a TCP client server communication. I'm sending string, and I would like to measure the size of the package, How can I do that?

In my case the [sys.getsizeof](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) is not good because

```
getsizeof() calls the object’s __sizeof__ method and adds an additional garbage collector
overhead if the object is managed by the garbage collector.
```

What is the size of one character, 2 or 4 byte? In this case I can simply measure as `msg_size = x * len(msg)`, but I don't know how many byte is `x`

Comment: len(string) returns the number of bytes used by the string (len(ustring) returns the number of chars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2.x, `str` objects are 8-bit i.e. 1 byte per item.  In 3.x you can use `bytes` objects which again are 1 byte per item.

For dealing with data, it's usually better to use [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray); this is mutable and works the same in both 2.x and 3.x.